# How can I generate the $JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security directory for openjdk-12?

Tags: java, buildroot

I'm trying to download a file over HTTPS in a jar using openjdk-12-jre on Buildroot. I would prefer to not have to modify the jar. The jar launches but dies with an error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Can not initialize cryptographic mechanism
    at java.base/javax.crypto.JceSecurity.<clinit>(JceSecurity.java:118)
    ... 21 more
Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Can't read cryptographic policy directory: unlimited
    at java.base/javax.crypto.JceSecurity.setupJurisdictionPolicies(JceSecurity.java:324)
    at java.base/javax.crypto.JceSecurity.access$000(JceSecurity.java:73)
    at java.base/javax.crypto.JceSecurity$1.run(JceSecurity.java:109)
    at java.base/javax.crypto.JceSecurity$1.run(JceSecurity.java:106)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.base/javax.crypto.JceSecurity.<clinit>(JceSecurity.java:105)
    ... 21 more
```

After some Googling the error seems to stem from missing a directory under `$JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security/`.

There was a workaround on the Debian issue tracker that involved creating a symlink - but it was outdated. Further, I am missing a large chunk of necessary files since the Buildroot install is quite minimal.

I also tried stealing the certificate store from my computer, but nothing changed - perhaps because of the difference in architecture?

How can I get Buildroot to generate the cacerts for OpenJDK?